# Select after bulk insert doesn't work in MS access database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, insert, oledb

There is a windows form application. I am using the **MS Access** database for some data manipulation. I want to copy data from one database to another. The table name, schema and the data types are same in both the tables.

I am using the below query to bulk insert data in destination database by selecting data from the source database.

```
INSERT INTO [Table1] IN 'C:\Data\Users.mdf' SELECT * FROM [Table1]
```

After data is inserted, I am querying to the target table to fetch the inserted data. I am using OleDbConnection for performing the database operations.

The issue I am facing here is that, after the above mentioned INSERT query is executed when I am executing the SELECT statement to fetch the data, I am not getting the data. However, when I am checking in debugging mode then I am getting the data.

I noticed that if I am waiting for some time after the INSERT statement is executed then the data is coming correctly. So I assume that it needs some time(delay?) to complete the bulk insert operation.

I tried providing `Task.Delay(20000)` after the INSERT query execution but no luck. Could someone help me here, how I can resolve this issue? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How much data are we talking about? And have you opened the table up to look through it and check that the data is going in properly? I would probably just import the source table into the target database and execute an appropriately re-written query. Then it at least eliminates problems that could be occurring in the communication between two separate databases.

Comment: There are around 7 lakh records. But I am able to replicate this issue with 10 records as well. The database connections are open for both source and target databases before INSERT operation takes place.

Comment: i'd suggest you post the whole procedure.

Comment: Sometimes this is resolved by executing the insert from inside a transaction. Begin the transaction, execute the statement, then commit the transaction. To do this you'll have to declare a workspace object in order to open/close a transaction, but when I want to force the commit of the data faster, this is sometimes the trick to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a good way to handle this but did a work around for the same. After data is inserted into the table, I am firing another query to check whether there is any data in the inserted table or not. This happens in a `do..while` loop like follows. The table is dropped every time the operation is completed.

```
        var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO [Table1] IN 'C:\Data\Users.mdf' SELECT * FROM [Table1]";
        ExecuteQuery(insertQuery, connProd);

        var count = 10;

        do
        {
            var selectQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM " + tableProdCopy;
            var dtTopRowData = GetQueryData(selectQuery, connOther);

            if (dtTopRowData != null && dtTopRowData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                count = 0;
                break;
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            count = count - 1;
        } while (count > 0);


        private DataTable GetQueryData(string query, OleDbConnection conn)
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmdOutput = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapterOutput = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdOutput))
                {
                    var dtOutput = new DataTable();

                    adapterOutput.Fill(dtOutput);

                    return dtOutput;
                }
            }
        }



        private void ExecuteQuery(string query, OleDbConnection conn)
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmdInput = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmdInput.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```